# Problems with starting to program Nao

Tags: ros, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and Nao and I've got little trouble in finding the right starting point.

I followed the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu and installed ROS in a Ubuntu Virtualbox and made some of the tutorials for ROS.

I also installed Naoqi and followed the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote to install the Nao-hydro packages.

Everything works fine so far but what is missing for me in this tutorials is something like "How to make the Nao say Hello World" :)

How to start writing the first program for the Nao? Where do I have to put my files and how do I have to compile them? I think some link in my brain is missing at the moment :)

I'm at this point since 3 days now, so please can someone point me the right way to my first working program on the Nao?

Thanks in advance

P.S.: Can someone please format the links for me? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109421/problems-with-starting-to-program-nao/) by [Tiamat](https://answers.ros.org/users/9791/tiamat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a "Getting started" tutorial here:
http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started

Beware that the installation instructions are outdated (replaced by the ones you linked), so you should directly jump to 1.6 ("Launching") and adjust the instructions as needed for the new Nao stacks.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tiamat](https://answers.ros.org/users/9791/tiamat/) on 2013-12-11**:
Thanks for your answer. I found this tutorial before (sorry I forgot to mention) and tried section 6 till 8 so I think everything should be working. But I don't know how to start writing my own stuff.
I also read through the SDK documentation but the link between sdk and ros is missing in my brain :)

**Comment by [Tiamat](https://answers.ros.org/users/9791/tiamat/) on 2013-12-11**:
What I want to do is getting this tutorial http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/cpp/examples/core/sayhelloworld/sayhelloworld.html#cpp-tutos-say-helloworld working with ROS. But I don't know where I have to put my code and so on. Stupid question I know :)

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-12-11**:
The link between the SDK and ROS is nao_driver: http://wiki.ros.org/nao_driver

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-12-11**:
Find the functionality you wan there (nao_speech), start the node, and publish to the corresponding topic ("speech"). There are multiple ways to do that in ROS, e.g. from command line or writing a C++/Python publisher (check ROS beginner tutorials).

**Comment by [Tiamat](https://answers.ros.org/users/9791/tiamat/) on 2013-12-12**:
Ok I'll try this maybe I'm just thinking to complex and it's much more easier :) Thank you!

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-12-12**:
It really is easy: `rostopic pub "/speech" std_msgs/String "Hello World"`